# Spring testcontainer test hangs when trying to simulate no connection to Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, testcontainers

I'm trying to simulate that the Mongo database is down when the query is run. I'm using testcontainers with Toxiproxy and Mongo.

In the below test class, test called *withLatency* work as expected but test *withoutConnection* is hanging.

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ToxiproxyIssueApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToxiproxyIssueApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Document
public record Person(String name, int age) {
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

The properties file contains:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

The test:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
class ToxiproxyIssueApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    private static final Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    private static final DockerImageName dockerImageName = DockerImageName.parse("mongo:5.0.5").asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mongo");

    @Container
    static final MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer = new MongoDBContainer(dockerImageName)
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("mongo");
//          .withReuse(true);

    @Container
    private static final ToxiproxyContainer toxiproxy = new ToxiproxyContainer("ghcr.io/shopify/toxiproxy:2.6.0")
            .withNetwork(network);

    private static Proxy mongoProxy;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void mongoProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) throws IOException {
        ToxiproxyClient toxiproxyClient = new ToxiproxyClient(toxiproxy.getHost(), toxiproxy.getControlPort());
        mongoProxy = toxiproxyClient.createProxy("mongodb", "0.0.0.0:8666", "mongo:27017");

        int port = mongoDbContainer.getMappedPort(27017);
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.host", toxiproxy::getHost);
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.port", () -> toxiproxy.getMappedPort(8666));
    }


    @Test
    void withLatency() throws IOException {
        mongoProxy.toxics().latency("mongo-latency", ToxicDirection.DOWNSTREAM, 2600).setJitter(100);
        var result = personRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(result).isEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    void withoutConnection() throws IOException {
        mongoProxy.toxics().bandwidth("no-connection-downstream", ToxicDirection.DOWNSTREAM, 0);
        mongoProxy.toxics().bandwidth("no-connection-upstream", ToxicDirection.UPSTREAM, 0);
        var result = personRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(result).isEmpty();

        mongoProxy.toxics().get("no-connection-downstream").remove();
        mongoProxy.toxics().get("no-connection-upstream").remove();
    }
}
```

When the test is hanging I see in the logs a timeout from the driver:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
```

Is there something wrong in my config or is this a testcontainer bug?

P.S the code posted should be enough to reproduce the issue.

**Later edit**

Based on the discussion from [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/7618) there is no bug. The client library is the one who provides the behavior. So further research will be conducted on this side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Toxiproxy documentation, there is the down toxic (https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy#down): by disabling the proxy no traffic will be routed.

In java Toxiproxy client library there are some methods to enable and disable the proxy: https://github.com/trekawek/toxiproxy-java/blob/7c5ffc5d7aa4780bd2ea73ad945f0227793a7e3d/src/main/java/eu/rekawek/toxiproxy/Proxy.java#L70-L76

Thus, the mentioned failed test will be rewritten as:

```
@Test
void withoutConnection() throws IOException {
    mongoProxy.disable();
    assertThatThrownBy(()->personRepository.findAll()).isInstanceOf(Exception.class);
    mongoProxy.enable();
    var result = personRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(result).isEmpty();
}
```